# highlight the current thread in mutt, but not in thread mode

Tags: mutt

A sample mail structure in mutt:

```
- L1: thread1 mail1
- L2: thread2 mail1
- L3: thread2 mail2 (cursor here)
- L4: thread3 mail1
- L5: thread1 mail2
- L6: thread3 mail2
- L7: thread1 mail3
- L8: thread2 mail3
- L9: thread1 mail4
- L10: thread2 mail4
```

In mutt, I want to set some feature like this: when the cursor is on a mail in a thread (L3 in thread2), highlight the mails that belong to the same thread. When I move the cursor to a mail in a different thread, the mails in that thread should become highlighted automatically.

Is it possible to do this in mutt?

References for mutt color scheme:

```conf
### # index
color index red default "~D(!~p|~p)" # deleted
color index brightred default ~=  # duplicate messages
color index brightgreen default "~A!~N!~T!~p!~Q!~F!~D!~P"  # the rest
color index J_base default "~A~N!~T!~p!~Q!~F!~D"  # the rest, new
color index red default "~A" # all messages
color index brightred default "~E" # expired messages
color index         brightmagenta   default         "~N"                        # new messages
color index         black            default         "~O"                        # old messages
color index         magenta         default         "~Q"                        # messages that have been replied to
color index         brightgreen     default        "~R"                        # read messages
color index         blue            default         "~U"                        # unread messages
color index         blue            default         "~U~$"                      # unread, unreferenced messages
color index         brightyellow    default         "~v"                        # messages part of a collapsed thread
color index         default         default         "~P"                        # messages from me
color index         cyan            default         "~p!~F"                     # messages to me
color index         cyan            default         "~N~p!~F"                   # new messages to me
color index         cyan            default         "~U~p!~F"                   # unread messages to me
color index         brightgreen     default         "~R~p!~F"                   # messages to me
color index brightyellow default "~F(~r <3d)" # flagged
color index brightred default "~F(!~N !~D)" # flagged
color index red default "~F~p" # flagged messages to me
color index red default "~N~F" # new flagged messages
color index red default "~N~F~p" # new flagged messages to me
color index         red             default         "~U~F~p"                    # new flagged messages to me
color index         black           red             "~D"                        # deleted messages
color index         white             default         "~v~(!~N)"                  # collapsed thread with no unread
color index         yellow          default         "~v~(~N)"                   # collapsed thread with some unread
color index         green           default         "~N~v~(~N)"                 # collapsed thread with unread parent

### for collapsed thread
color index red black  "~v~(~F)!~N"  # collapsed thread with flagged, no unread
color index yellow black "~v~(~F~N)" # collapsed thread with some unread & flagged
color index green black "~N~v~(~F~N)" # collapsed thread with unread parent & flagged
color index green black "~N~v~(~F)" # collapsed thread with unread parent, no unread inside, but some flagged
color index cyan black "~v~(~p)" # collapsed thread with unread parent, no unread inside, some to me directly
color index yellow  red "~v~(~D)" # thread with deleted (doesn't differentiate between all or partial)
color index yellow default "~(~N)" # messages in threads with some unread
color index green default "~S" # superseded messages
```